# 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

```
        txtusername.Text = UserGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtphone.Text = UserGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txtpass.Text= UserGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtconfirm.Text= UserGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        txtemail.Text= UserGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
```

what is the wrong here

When i going to click the grideview row values , the value should be appear in the text box for update

Comment: Given the code shown, either `UserGV.SelectedRows` has zero elements or `UserGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells` has fewer than five elements.